# Javascript MVC with custom HTML elements - notifying controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, custom-element

I have written custom HTML elements whose constructors and definitions themselves are in classes. I have done this in order to create a view. However, I need to create an app with a MVC, model-view-controller design pattern. I've seen several posts but all of them involve standard HTML elements. How can I do this with my custom HTML elements (tho not web-components; they don't use a shadow DOM)

ps: i'm not using Jquery but rather standard selectors.

Comment: Show us an example of your custom html output.

Comment: @TravisActon what do you mean 'output?' well my custom elements include buttons and text fields. do you mean: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my page</title>
     ...
    <script src="file2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="file1.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article-link></article-link>
    <ul id="lists">
      <experiment-bucket></experiment-bucket>
    </ul>
    <plus-button></plus-button>
    <br>
    <submit-button></submit-button>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Give us an example of your non-standard html elements and we can show you how to convert it properly to razor syntax. As of now your question is not focused on a single problem and is generic enough that you probably won't get an applicable answer.

Comment: @TravisActon here's an example: class SubmitAndCreate extends HTMLElement{
 
 constructor(){
  super();  
 }

 connectedCallback(){
  const submitbutton = document.createElement('button');
  submitbutton.setAttribute('type','submit');
  submitbutton.setAttribute('id','submitButton');
  submitbutton.innerHTML = "Submit Test";

  submitbutton.addEventListener('click',this.gatherBucketData.bind(this));

  this.appendChild(submitbutton);
 }

 ...

}

customElements.define('submit-button', SubmitAndCreate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MVC pattern for Custom Elements just like with standard Javascript.

Define:

- one `object` (or a `class`) for the **Controller**
- one for the **Model**
- one for the **View**

There are many ways to define and to interconnect the Model, View and Controller.

---

#### Custom Element specific

Adapted to the Custom Element, you can either:

- define the Custom Element class (extending `HTMLElement`) as the **Controller**
- define the Custom Element class as the **View**
- define the the **Model**, **View** and **Controller** inside the Custom Element `class`
- define the 3 entities outside the Custom Element `class`
- etc.

---

#### Example

In the minimalist example implemented below:

- the Custom Element `class` defines the **Controller**
- the **Model** is declared in the Controller as a `function`
- then the **View** is declared in the Controller as a `function`, too

This way the View can access the Model (for data reading) and the Controller directly.

```js
//CONTROLLER
class PersonController extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {             
        let controller = this 
        let elem = this

        //MODEL
        function PersonModel () {
            //Model API
            this.load = async id => {
                let res = await fetch( `https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}` )
                let json = await res.json()
                Object.assign( this, json.data )
                controller.updateView()
            }
        }                

        let model = new PersonModel

        //VIEW
        function PersonView () {
            elem.innerHTML = `
                Id : <input id=index type=number>
                <div id=card>Loading data
                </div>` 

            let card = elem.querySelector( 'div#card' )
            let index = elem.querySelector( 'input#index' )

            index.onchange = () => controller.init( index.value)               
            
            //View API
            this.update = () => {
                card.innerHTML = `
                    <div>Name : ${model.first_name} ${model.last_name}</div>
                    <div><img src=${model.avatar}></div>`
                index.value = model.id    
            }              
        }

        let view = new PersonView

        //Controller API
        this.init = id => model.load( id )               
        this.updateView = () => view.update() 

        //Init with some data 
        this.init( 4 )
    }
}

customElements.define( 'person-card', PersonController )
```

```css
person-card { display: inline-block ; background-color: lightblue }
person-card input { width: 50 }
```

```html
<person-card></person-card>
```

This example creates a `<person-card>` element with the MVC pattern that will fetch some data from a REST web service (at [reqres.in](https://reqres.in)) and show a person's name, id, and avatar.